# VBScript works from command line but doesn't work as ASP script

Tags: iis, dll, asp-classic, vbscript, activex

I've got the following code working as VBScript from command line:

```
Set FRELoader = Server.CreateObject( "FREngineWrap.FRELoader" )
Set Engine = FRELoader.Load
```

When I put it into ASP page:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Set FRELoader = Server.CreateObject( "FREngineWrap.FRELoader" )
Set Engine = FRELoader.Load
%>
```

it doesn't work:

Error Type:
(0x80004005)
Unspecified error 
/test.asp, line 4

I've got IIS 5.1 here

Comment: What does this thing do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is definitely in FREngineWrap.FRELoader, not in your ASP code.  Remember, when running from VBScript, the program runs in your user context - e.g. as user "MYDOMAIN\alex347".

When you run the program from ASP, it runs in whatever IIS security context you are using.  This often can cause problems, especially if the IIS user doesn't have access to files you have access to as MYDOMAIN\alex347.

If you have the source code to FRELoader, you might check and see where it throws an error.  Otherwise, you might have to try changing your IIS security settings.

EDIT: Here's a link for how to modify IIS so that it uses a different user's credentials.  Try changing IIS's credentials to your username and see if it works.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708(v=ws.10)

Answer (score 0):

That is a database connection error. Check your connection string.

Comment: I don't use any databases. As I mentioned it works from command line

Comment: @alex347 Maybe `FRELoader.Load` uses a db? Is that your code?